# Reset Duplicate Values in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, random, duplicates

I have a PHP array:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,3,4,6,6);
```

I want to find the location of either duplicate in each duplicate pair (either 3 and either 6) and reset that value using rand(1,8).  How would I go about doing this?  I essentially need to make sure all of the array values are different.

Comment: No, I've looked through PHP functions, but am having difficulty returning the key/index of the duplicate element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,3,4,6,6);
$dup = array_diff_assoc($arr,array_unique($arr));
$v = mt_rand(1, 8);

foreach ( $dup as $k ) {
    while ( in_array($v, $arr) ) {
        $v = mt_rand(1, 8);
    }
    $arr[$k] = $v;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to record how many items are in the array, use array_unique, and finally refill the array using a rand:

```
$size = count($arr);
$arr = array_unique($arr);
while (count($arr) < $size) {
  $arr[] = rand(1,8,$arr);
}
```

You'd want to repeat this until count($arr) == count(array_unique($arr)). You could also make a random function that gives random values that are not already in the array pretty easily using in_array() and a loop.